# Axis webservice error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-services, axis

I have written a simple java file Calculator.java as below

```
public class Calculator {
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a+b;
    }
    public int subtract(int a, int b) {
        return a-b;
    }
}
```

Now, i renamed it to Calculator.jws and put it in my web application's root directory. (in the same directory as the WEB-INF directory). When i try to access this webservice using http://localhost:8680/webappcontextroot/Calculator.jws i get a message saying

"There is a Web Service here. Click to see the WSDL"

When i click on the link to see the WSDL file i get an error,

AXIS error

Could not generate WSDL!

There is no SOAP service at this location

When i wrote a client to invoke the web service, i get an Axis fault

```
- Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
Exception in thread "main" AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}Server.NoService
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: The AXIS engine could not find a target service to invoke!  targetService is null
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:D78D46BS
```

The AXIS engine could not find a target service to invoke!  targetService is null

The WSDL file seems to be missing; but the oreilly tutorial tells all you have to do is just copy your java file to a .jws file and put it in your webapp and the webservice is ready to use.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

solely on the error message, it seems that your are missing mailapi.jar and activation.jar libraries in your classpath. Put those in the same folder where your axis.jar is and restart the web server.